# Understanding UnicodeScalar initializers in Swift

Tags: ios, string, swift, unicode

If we then look at the struct `UnicodeScalar`, we see this initializer:

```
init(_ v: UInt32)
```

But you can do this without any problem :

```
println(UnicodeScalar("a").value)
```

An it prints out:

```
97
```

But if you try it to do this :

```
let a : Character = "a"  // With String gave error too        
println(UnicodeScalar(a).value)
```

Its give you an error regarding the initializer of the `UnicodeScalar` struct.

I assume that in the first case it make a implicit cast or something in the initializer , but why not in the second case?

How can avoid the error in the seconde case using a declared variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"a"` is not like `a`. `a` is a variable, so its type is Character or String. `"a"` is a *literal*, and its type is StringLiteralConvertible. That is why `"a"` can be used in places that `a` cannot be used.

(The same is true for literals in general in Swift. You can use the literal `9` in places where you cannot use an Int variable whose value is 9.)

Perhaps you are looking for something like this:

```
let c  = "a"
let v = c.unicodeScalars
let u = v[v.startIndex]
println(u.value)
```

Comment: But I can't do this neither `let a : StringLiteralConvertible  = "a"`. Please can you explain if there is a way to to do it?

Comment: Sorry, a way to do what? I don't understand. Your question was not how to _do_ anything, but _why_ something.

Comment: Sorry @matt , my mistake, what I ask is if there is a way to avoid this error in the second case with a declared variable?

Comment: Don't be sorry, I just didn't grasp the issue. I've expanded my answer to provide some possibly useful code.