# Swift -How to add an image and text to the left view of a UItextField and have them line up evenly vertically

Tags: ios, swift, string, image, uitextfield

I currently have an image and 2 strings that I add to a button and I add the button to a uiview that I add to the left side of a textField. I take the image and 2 strings and make one complete string by first converting the image to a NSTextAttachment and then appending the other 2 strings to the end of it.

It works but the problem is the image (downArrow) is too big compared to the 2 strings and it appears to sit directly in the centerY of the textField while the 2 strings sit towards the lower bottom of the textField.

(the red background is just to highlight the uiview that I use that the button sits inside)

[image]

The [emoji flag is a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30403199/4833705) not an image

I thought to myself maybe the best way to remedy this is to first set the downArrow image to the left side of the textField and then add the 2 strings to the button and put the button on the left side of the downArrow. The only problem with that is eventually I want the paddingView the button is in to be the exact width of all 3 strings so that width doesn't have all the empty space at the beginning and the end of the red view.

**Just for clarity what I want to do is have the downArrow and the 2 strings line up vertically all on 1 line. Depending on the outcome of this I'll ask how to to get the width of all 3 in another question.**

I tried setting the button's `contentVerticalAlignment = .center` but it made no difference.

```
// button
var flagButton = UIButton()
flagButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = .fill
flagButton.contentVerticalAlignment = .center // I tried .fill too
flagButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit // I tried .scaleAspectFill too
flagButton.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)

// downArrow, emoji flag, and dialing code that will get displayed inside the button
let emojiFlag = // emoji flag from string
let dialingCode = // country dialing code is a String

let flagAndDialingCode = "\(emojiFlag) \(dialingCode)"

let fullString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: " ", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)])
let image1Attachment = NSTextAttachment()
image1Attachment.image = UIImage(named: "downArrow")
let image1String = NSAttributedString(attachment: image1Attachment)
fullString.append(image1String)
fullString.append(NSAttributedString(string: flagAndDialingCode))

flagButton.setAttributedTitle(fullString, for: .normal)

// button will go on the left side of this textField
phoneNumberTextField.layoutIfNeeded()

let height = phoneNumberTextField.frame.size.height
let width: CGFloat = 100 // this width should actually be the width of the image and 2 strings together

let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
flagButton.frame = frame

let paddingView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
paddingView.backgroundColor = .red
paddingView.addSubview(flagButton)

phoneNumberTextField.leftViewMode = .always
phoneNumberTextField.leftView = paddingView
```

Comment: Did you try making the emoji string containing view and the down arrow containing view to same height as their parent view and then centring them vertically ?

Comment: the emoji, down arrow, and dialing code are all strings that are set inside the button’s setSetTitle() func. let downArrowTextAttchEmojiStrDialCodeStr = “\\(downArrow) \\(emojiStr) \\(dialCode)” ; flagButton.setAttributedTitle(downArrowTextAttachEmojiStrDislCodeStr, for: .normal). Is what you suggested possible to do within a button?

Comment: Have you tried this.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954880/left-align-image-and-center-text-on-uibutton.     . Using UIedge inset ??

Comment: the contentHorizontalAlignment is in my question and the accompanying code.

Comment: @pooja I’ll try using the edgeinset and get back to you